# Chrome and Opera html entity disappearing -- OS X?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, opera

It seems as though when the viewport is set to a height larger than an unknown amount, the winking emoji entity disappears but the `X` doesn't! This only happens in Chrome and Opera on OS X (not windows).

I have formulated a jsfiddle with my problem http://jsfiddle.net/www139/d4fcfazn/.

Here is a code snippet for you :)

```css
body,
html {
  font-size: 50vh;
  line-height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
&#128521; &#10006;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It works as expected on Chrome 47 (Windows 10) for me.

Comment: I'm using OS X, maybe that could be it?

Comment: Check if changing the font family has impact on the rendering.

Comment: @Alex I have now tested it inside my Virtual machine for Windows. It works. This question is OS X specific :)

Comment: Do you have any ballpark information about which screen size and/or fint sizes we're talking about here? Any information is welcome! (I can't test myself, being as I am on Linux, but maybe OSX people can use this.)

Comment: Also, you're talking about the "entity", so... does this also happen when you put the character in directly instead of using a numerical reference?

Comment: The entity is an emoji which you cannot type as far as I know.

Comment: @www139 Yes you can. Run the code snippet and then you can copy it from the screen and paste it in any text editor! [Here, a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/tmyvbgq3/).